# Register tlb COM with regasm

Tags: c#, com, regasm

I have **.NET assembly**.

I am trying to register it for COM interop so that I can call it from **VBA**, using the following command:

**regasm foo.dll /tlb:foo.tlb /codebase**

When I did it on my pc, I could use it without any kind of problem. The code in **VBA** worked. The problem is when I regasm (with the same sentence) in other pc, it seems registering well (regasm says it) but when I execute the code in VBA, it throws an error for not finding the type. Reference is mounted correctly.

Comment: Make sure you call the right version of regasm on the other machine, either from Framework64 or in Framework (for x86).

Answer (score 2):

Start up Excel.  Go to task manager and find it in the list of processes.  If it says "excel.exe" then you are running a 64-bit process (or 32-bits if on a 32-bit OS).  If it says "excel.exe *32", then you are running a 32-bit process on a 64-bit OS.

I expect that the problem is because you are running a 64-bit version of Office.

So, steps:

1. Find cmd.exe and launch it as Administrator -- you have to have elevated privileges
2. Run the 64-bit version of regasm.exe when you register.  For a normal installation, "c:\windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework64\v2.0.50727\regasm.exe foo.dll /tlb /codebase".  If you build it against another version of .Net, use that version instead of 2.0.50727.